# React.js - Material-ui DataGrid disable row width

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Is it possible to change the width of a row? I have some rows with JSON data. It would be best to display them in a <pre> tag so that the user can view it naturally, but this seems to be impossible.

So now I'm wondering is it possible to remove the default `overflow-x: hidden`? And to just let the user scroll to the end of a row? Instead of the text just having 3 dots at the end, because there's a max-width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [data-grid css api](https://material-ui.com/api/data-grid/#css) they show the necessary classes which could be overridden, and at the end they say:

> You can override the style of the component thanks to one of these customization points
> ...

So you could add the following style rule to override the default one :

```
.MuiDataGrid-root .MuiDataGrid-cell {
  text-overflow: initial;
     overflow-x: auto;
}
```

[image: Edit Material demo (forked)]

Comment: Problem is that when you do this and remove the overflow on the viewport it doesn't allow you to scroll to the right it seems like.

Comment: You could add `overflow: auto;` rule